# Is it correct to call systems with agents without BDI multi-agent systems?

Tags: dc.distributed-comp, ai.artificial-intel

The question concerns two fields - multiagent systems in AI and in software engineering. As the source of the term comes from the AI field, I ask the question here.

Traditionally multiagent system (MAS) is understood as a system with BDI agents - i.e. field of AI.
But in software engineering by MAS they sometimes call systems that just consist of agents with behaviour,
like peer-to-peer networks, regardless if they have such intelligent aspects as belief, desire, intelligence.
Is it correct to use MAS word for such systems?

I've checked wiki (multiagent system, agent based model, software agent), googled, checked relevant journals etc but the issue is still vague.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After asking one kind scientist my implications are:
"MAS" could be used for agents with explicit or implicit BDI.
Or sometimes even with kinda obscurious BDI.
But not for "passive" components, even if they are active but don't have initiative.

Comment: and sorry if I've asked the answer in the wrong place. Had feeling that to answer one should know distributed and artificial intelligence systems as well.